# Using Python SDK export Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, splunk

I am trying to use Python SDK to export Data from Splunk.

```
for result in rr:
if isinstance(result, results.Message):
    # Diagnostic messages might be returned in the results
    print '%s: %s' % (result.type, result.message)
elif isinstance(result, dict):
    # Normal events are returned as dicts
    print result
assert rr.is_preview == False
```

The output data is like:

```
OrderedDict([('TIME','1'),('UID','BUSINESS')])
OrderedDict([('TIME','12'),('UID','ACC')])
OrderedDict([('TIME','33'),('UID','TRAVEL')])
```

I am not sure how to transfer the data to dataframe. I read the document it said ResultsReader is iterable and returns a dict for result. I tried Pandas_DataFrame(rr) and it does not work shows data argument can't be an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Use syntax below.

```
import splunklib.client as client
import splunklib.results as results
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

# Retrieve results using syntax below. Change SPL accordingly.
rr = results.ResultsReader(service.jobs.export("search index=<xxxxxxxxxxxx>")

df = pd.DataFrame(list(rr))
print(df)

  TIME       UID
0    1  BUSINESS
1   12       ACC
2   33    TRAVEL
```